# NoMethodError in Articles#new undefined method `errors' for nil:NilClass in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm so confused. I was following steps on rails guide, trying to make a blog, but I kept getting `NoMethodError in Articles#new: undefined method` errors' for nil:NilClass`
Here's my controller thought I have the right 'new' method here

```rb
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @articles = Article.all
  end
  
  def show
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @article = Article.new
  end

  def edit
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  end
  
  def create
    @article = Article.new(article_params)
        
    if @article.save
      redirect_to @article
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
end
```

then I kept getting error after add @article.errors.any? to new.html.erb

```
<%= form_with model: @article, local: true do |form| %>

<% if @article.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2>
        <%= pluralize(@article.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited
.....
<% end %>
```

Really want to know what's wrong with the code.
Is there anything that I missed?

Thank you

Comment: When you get this error? When you are visiting `/articles/new`? The stack trace might be helpful.

Comment: The indentation of your controller is confusing. When you fix it you will see that it is missing an `end` at the end.

Comment: thanks you guys, I restart computer the other day and magically it has no errors at all! so weird :